# How to configure two mails in application context in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-batch

In spring application context i have to use two mails which is send one email for some methods and another email should be used for other methods. Can anyone help me please?

```
<bean name="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="username" value="email11" />
    <property name="password" value="*****" />
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.office365.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">587</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

true
                smtp.office365.com
                587
                true

like above i have to use one more  is it possible

Comment: What is the difference in these two mails ? Does the smtp change ?, you don't you use the same bean for both emails ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same bean definition with a different bean name.